# how to see if any timer thread is running or not

Tags: linux, timer, posix

I wrote a program to schedule a periodic timer in LINUX using `timer_create` and `timer_settime`.

What will happen if I kill the process before deleting and stopping this timer? Will the timer stay alive even after exiting from main.

If yes, how can I check if any such timer is still running after killing the main?

Answer (score 0):

The man page of [timer_create(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/timer_create.2.html) says that :

```
   Timers are not inherited by the child of a fork(2), and are disarmed and
   deleted during an execve(2).
```

So you should not bother about timers after their creating process exits or terminates (e.g. is killed).

On Linux, you could parse `/proc/timer_list` and `/proc/timer_stats` to query the kernel about timers.

It is the kernel's responsibility to manage [process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) specific resources (like file descriptors, address space, timers, etc...). Trust the kernel on that, it will release appropriately such resources, as mentioned in the [fork(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/fork.2.html) and [execve(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/execve.2.html) man pages.

Read more about [linux kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel) role and [system calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call).

Comment: I am a newbie .. can you tell me in whose context the timers run .. I was of the opinion that the timers run in the context of kernel so whenever the main process exits before deleting the timer , it would continue to exist

Comment: What do you mean by *context* ??? Posix timers are used by applications thru timer related system calls (e.g. `timer_create`, `timer_settime` etc...). This should be enough for you. How the kernel implements timers is an implementation detail, applications interact with the kernel *only* thru **system calls**.

Comment: ok let me ask the same question again .. won't the timer continue to exist in the POSIX library

Comment: You asked: "Won't the timer continue to exist in the POSIX library"? But once a process is terminated, it has no address space! So your question don't have any sense (or I misunderstood your question).